# How can I know the values in CABasicAnimation keyPath

Tags: iphone, calayer, cabasicanimation

I find some code like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
anim.keyPath = @"transform.scale";
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
anim.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"scaleOut"];
```

and

```
anim.keyPath = @"transform.rotation.x";
```

As far as I know, keyPath is a chained method invoke. "transform.scale" for CALayer is aLayer.transform.scale. "transform" is a property of CALayer, "scale" is a 'property' of transform. But property transform in CALayer is CATransform3D.

There is no property named "scale" or "rotation" in CATransform3D.

My Question is:
How "scale" and "rotation" are identified by keyPath ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Core Animation extends KVC to support direct addressing of fields (or pseudo fields) of some struct-type properties of layers. The feature is described in [Core Animation Extensions To Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW8).

Comment: For example, `scale.xy` is not in that list. So it's not complete. Where should I find all key paths or the missing ones?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230796/what-is-the-full-keypath-list-for-cabasicanimation

Comment: @Honey, It still doesn't contain `scale.xy`, and maybe the reason is that `scale.yx` works too, so there are a lot of combinations. But nor the answer nor the documentation seem to mention this option of combining them.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure, but I found a solution that could probably help.

**IN SWIFT:**
Instead of writing a String you can use this:

```
let shadowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.shadowRadius))
```

When you type CALayer. <- autocomplete should give you the available keyPaths.

I hope this helps.

Comment: OMG couldn't Apple just create an enum for this? still can't find `"transform.rotation.z"` in this method