# iOS Obj-c gradient background transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, gradient

I'd like to gradually change the background gradient from

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor.blackColor CGColor],(id)[UIColor.blueColor CGColor], nil];
```

to

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor.grayColor CGColor],(id)[UIColor.cyanColor CGColor], nil];
```

**[EDIT]** My current code is:

```
                gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor.blackColor CGColor],(id)[UIColor.blueColor CGColor], nil];
                NSArray *fromColors = gradient.colors;
                NSArray *toColors =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor.grayColor CGColor],(id)[UIColor.cyanColor CGColor], nil];
                CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"colors"];

                animation.fromValue = fromColors;
                animation.toValue = toColors;
                animation.duration = 3.00;
                animation.removedOnCompletion = false;
                animation.autoreverses = NO;
                animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
                if (![gradient.animationKeys containsObject:@"colors"]) {
                    [gradient addAnimation:animation forKey:@"colors"];
                }
                [self.background.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

But it doesn't do anything. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "colors" are supported in CABasicAnimation.keypath.But how to meet the requirement, I still can't think of the answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459673/how-can-i-know-the-values-in-cabasicanimation-keypath

Comment: Thank you, the trick is add "backgroundColor" as keypath

Comment: However, adding "backgroundColor" change the background to a one color background, not gradient. The keypath colors was right, but I had made a mistake: I had two gradients, self.gradient and gradient. Noob errors happen sometimes